# Insert random data from one column to a column in another table

Tags: sql

I'm wanting to insert random data from one field into another.  I'm unsure of the syntax for this completely, So I'm thinking

icdtbl.icd_id = primary key
icdjxn.icd_id = foreign key

```
  insert into icdjxn (icd_id,patiendID)

    select top 5000 icd_id from icdtbl order by newid(),select top 5000 patientID from patientTbl order by newid()
```

edited for the entirety of what i was looking for.

Comment: There is no way in SQL (aside from maybe using a cursor?) to select random data. All queries execute deterministically given the same dataset

Comment: @HLGEM: msg 156, incorrect syntax near the keyword select

Comment: if you order by newid() it will give you a random subset of a table.  These do not need to be unique and preferably will not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into icdjxn (icd_id)  
select top 5000 icd_id from icdtbl order by newid()
```

You don't use the word values when using a select.

Comment: could you use this same logic insert two random pieces of data at the same time? (the other side of this junction table)